# How to react to Mouse Scroll Wheel on ToolStripDropDownButton's DropDownMenu?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a normal WinForms ToolStripDropDownButton's drop down menu that is populated dynamically.  In some cases the number of items on the drop down extend beyond the screen dimensions and the overflow up/down scroll buttons appear.

Instead of the user clicking on the overflow buttons to bring the rest of the menu items into view, is it possible have the same behavior with the mouse wheel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those controls don't handle the Mouse Wheel inherently, so there is no way to make it happen without busting things open with Reflection - which will have it's own problems.